# Remove unwanted dots from URL and don't stop checking htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to remove unwanted dots from urls like:
/en/example-.product

I want to redirect this example link to:
/en/example-product

We cannot delete dots right before extensions of files, like .png .jpg .css etc.

Dot appears randomly in url, so it can be anywhere, also there could be more than 1 of them:

- /en/example-.product
- /en/example.-product
- /en/ex.ample-product
- /en/ex.ample.-product
- /en/ex.amp.le.-product

My code so far - it makes server error.

```
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(.....+)$ /$1-$2 [N]
```

Also I am wondering how to let url to continue checking htaccess - because later I will add few extra rules, like removing "/en/" from url or redirecting old, unused pages. I know I cannot use R or L flag - but when I am trying to use "N" it is not working. Here is my another part of .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Do these _erroneous_ dots only appear in URLs that do not have file extensions (as in your examples)? Is there at most 1 erroneous dot in any one URL?

Comment: Right, unwanted dots appear only on URLs that do not have file extensions.

There are from 1 to max. 3 unwanted dots in links.